# World to screen XYZ to XY without knowing matrices

Tags: java, opengl, coordinates

How exactly can a world to screen be implemented without knowing all of the matrices involved in rendering?

Comment: What the...You're not really using plain numbers instead of GL constant identifiers, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gluProject` simply applies all of the given transforms to the point passed.  If you pass it the wrong transforms or the wrong point, you will get the wrong result.

For example, if you want the screen coordinate of the centre of an object, assuming that the objects untransformed coordinates are centered in (0,0,0), you can `gluProject` the coordinates (0,0,0), the modelview transform in effect when drawing that object, and the usual for projection and viewport.

and PLEASE use the standard constants! Using `2892` and similar in your code when there are perfectly good constants like `GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` makes baby Jesus cry.

Answer (score 2):

The transformation you made with gluproject is using the follwing system:

```
y
|
|
+------x
```

But your screen is using the following system:

```
+-------x
|
|
|
y
```

All you have to do is:

```
yCoord = window_height - yCoord;
```